# NPM Registry Error 503

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install

I want to compile my angular app while I got the error "npm ERR! 503 No healthy backends: gulp-cli@latest"
error stack:

```html
npm ERR! code E503
npm ERR! 503 No healthy backends: gulp-cli@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kevfan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-22T07_09_31_729Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! SaaSTransferApprovalTool@1.0.0 typings: `typings install && npm install gulp-cli -g`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the SaaSTransferApprovalTool@1.0.0 typings script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kevfan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-22T07_09_31_778Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! SaaSTransferApprovalTool@1.0.0 postinstall: `npm run typings`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the SaaSTransferApprovalTool@1.0.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kevfan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-22T07_09_31_884Z-debug.log
```

My npm registry is https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm version: 6.0.1
When I visit registry, the http status is 503, it's a server error, so is there any replacement registry that can visit?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes I can visit this site, it's unsteadiness

[image]